Make building on mesh islands
I'd like to randomly set the height of the buildings based on mesh islands. Also, I would like the material at the base, in the middle and on the roof to be different (like the colors on the building in the picture).


Possibly related: Place Instances based on face size


Note: This solution is not based on Mesh Islands as requested in the title, but on splines as shown in the questioner's nodetree (sorry for the confusion).

To extrude the curve upwards step by step using a Repeat Zone, you could use the following setup:

Here, I first create a random integer value in each individual spline in a range between 1 and the maximum number of floors.
Within the Repeat Zone, I then compare this value with the iteration.
If the iteration is less than or equal to the previously recorded value, a new floor is created.
At the same time, you can also use this comparison to assign a different material to the first and last floor.
(Blender 4.2.2+)

Works great !!! Thank You.

Hi, is there a simple way to add flat roof on last floor

@Mateusz88 There are actually several options here, but if you absolutely want to use curves here that should also be resampled, then you could solve this as follows: https://i.sstatic.net/26P5t3UM.png

Thank You one more time.

It's a bit awkward getting the field values to work correct in a repeat zone, but this seems to do the trick.
Just set the max number of iterations from a Group input, then every iteration compare the iteration number to a random value based on the mesh island index, use that values as the Extrude offset scale. Store the iteration number in the extruded geo for use later when assigning the materials.

Then outside the repeat zone, remove doubles to get rid of the levels that were extruded but not scaled, and use the floor number attribute to set the materials.

End result:


Good solution, but I think the Repeat Zone was intended to create multiple floors.

@quellenform Ah, I see now. Yeah idk how clear that was made by the question but still. I think this fits into the ultimate solution, even if it isn't the solution.

Yes, it could be solution but in my case I'd like to have floors so repeat zone is crucial

@Mateusz88 I revised my answer to something that I think better fits your question now that I understand it more clearly.
